# Displaying notification in the home page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, signalr

I am using signal r for displaying notification . The summary of my code is

1. I have a hub method which fetch the data from the database.
2. On my controller post method i am saving the data to database
3. On my notification page view i have a jquery code on button click event to send notification
4. On my Home page layout i have a div tab which recieves the notification(Calling my hub method to display the values).Currently it is a div

Here the problem i faced is my jquery click event is called and the send notification get called.But the http post event to save the data to table is not getting called.

I want to display the new notification count(say in red color) like we have in facebook and on click of that i want to expand the same and display the same. Means i want to implement the same facebook/stacoverflow notification functionality.Is it a div which is used in facebook for notification??

Can anyone show give some idea on how I can achieve the same with Hubclass:

```
public class NotificationHub:Hub
{
    private MyContext db = new MyContext();

    public void SendNotifications()
    {
        var ret = (from notification in db.Notifications.ToList()
                   select new
                   {
                       Message = notification.Text,
                       //PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                       //PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                     //  NotificationId = notification.NotificationID,
                   }).ToArray();
        //ret
        Clients.All.receiveNotification(ret);
    }
```

Controller Post method:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Notification(Notification notification)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Notifications.Add(notification);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //NotificationHub obj = new NotificationHub();
            //obj.SendNotifications();

        }

        return View(notification);
    }
```

View where jquery event is called

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div class="publishContainer">
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new { @placeholder = "Enter notification here!!" })
</div>
  <p>
   <input id="button1" type="button" value="button" />

@section Scripts
 {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {   var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;// Start the connection.$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { $("#button1").click(function () { notifications.server.sendNotifications(); }).fail(function (e) {  alert(e);
});
 });
});
</script>
```

and my home page

```
 $(function () {
    var proxy = $.connection.notificationHub;

    proxy.client.receiveNotification = function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var element = data[i];
            $('#discussion').append('<li>' + element.Message + '</li>');
        }
```

here notification is not getting saved to the db.
I want to display the new notification count(say in red color) like we have in facebook and on click of that i want to expand the same and display the same. Means i want to implement the same facebook/stacoverflow notification functionality.Is it a div which is used in facebook for notification??

Comment: Posting your code rather than explaining it is more likely to get you answers.

Comment: Thanks Mians for formatting the code. This is my first post in stackoverflow and i was not able to do it my self.

Comment: This question is still unclear.  It now seems like you're asking "Is it a div which is used in facebook for notifictation".  But that question has a yes/no answer for which the supplied code is mostly irrelevant.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My question is how can i implement notification using Asp.net MVC?

Comment: Any hand ? I am stucked with this implementation